# Significant differences between regression curves 

Tags: regression, curve-fitting

Currently, I´m analyzing data from seven regression curves. I´d like to know if there are significant differences between these lines. Although I thought the procedure was simple,   I´ve found that there are not well-defined tests to solve this, recently I found [this paper](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A17n315.pdf) which describes the general procedure.

Unfortunately I´m not statistician, so I´d like to know if there is a simpler test to perform this analysis and maybe an R package for it.

Comment: What do you want to test about them for different?  Does the height of the line matter, or only slope, or perhaps both?

Comment: Yes, both parameters are important, but I´m mainly interested about finding statistical differences among the slopes. Do you have any example? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this problem is well defined yet, you state that the data is from the curves?  Are you generating the data, or is it the same data?  When you say different curves, are the covariates the same, or just the coefficients different?